# How to get mac address of client system which accessing server system

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tcp, client-server

I have developed web application using J2EE(JSP,Servlet).I want to get the web user/client mac address, i.e i want to restrict the users to open my web application with register mac address only. So other systems could not open my web application,
For example, if the user entered URL in the browser and enters, the request will go to the server, in the server side is it possible to capture the mac address of the client?,if it is possible i can restrict him to open my application by checking with my already registered mac addresses.

I have read many solution but all against my question. I hope there must some new solution to do my requirement.

Please someone give me a new solution to achieve this one.

Comment: "I want to restrict the users to open my web application with register mac address only" That won't work. Are you aware that the MAC address can be changed by the user, and isn't unique? And what happens if the user changes his NIC? Do you really want to lock out a paying customer? Of course not. Don't use MAC addresses for security purposes.